# Error when extracting tar archive via CMake

Tags: cmake

I've got a `.tar` archive I'd like to unpack using CMake.

On Windows I get:

```
-- extracting... [tar xf]
CMake Error: Problem with archive_write_header(): Can't create '\\?\C:\'
CMake Error: Current file: /
```

On Linux (WSL) on the other hand:

```
user@pc-DellXPS13:~$ cmake -E tar xf archive.tar
CMake Error: Problem with archive_write_finish_entry(): Can't restore time
CMake Error: Problem extracting tar: archive.tar
user@pc-DellXPS13:~$
```

I can't really understand what's going on here.

The structure of the archive is the following:

```
user@pc-DellXPS13:~$ tar tf archive.tar
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/
Examples/EspHomeExample/partitions.csv
ReleaseNotes.txt
Copying.txt
Resources/
Resources/Data.bin
Build/
Build/RaspberryPi/CMakeLists.txt
Src/Main.c
Version.txt
```

Comment: What are the contents of that tar file? Add the output of `tar tf archive.tar`

Comment: @Botje added to the question

Comment: That / entry in your tar file should not be there. Can you recreate the tar file without that entry?

Comment: Yep. It's actually broader then that - each file should have `./` beforehand, so the creation of the `tar.gz` is bad. Thanks.